# HTML Text right next to a blink text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am using the blink text for one letter and that is "|". I have the code for the blink text already setup.

My question is. How do I put text to the left of the "|" that does not blink? I have been trying to do that. But when I put text to the left of the "|" the "|" seems to go underneath my text then.

My blink alternative code:

```
<p id="blink">|</p>
<script>
 var blacktime = 400;
 var whitetime = 400;

 setTimeout(whiteFunc,blacktime);
 function whiteFunc(){
 document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "white";
 setTimeout(blackFunc,whitetime);
}
 function blackFunc(){
 document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "black";
 setTimeout(whiteFunc,blacktime);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's probably because you have placed a single character inside a paragraph tag which comes with some default styling. Try putting it into a span instead and see what happens.

Comment: As @csm_dev points out, you should do: `<p><span id="blink">|</span>
 your text</p>`

Comment: TSR I have tried doing that but the "|" goes to the bottom.

Comment: Stuart that works very well! Now I just need to use it for the left side not the right.

Answer (score 2):

#### Wrap the "|" inside of a `<span>`

The `<p>`-element in an html block element, which means that everything that is not wrapped inside the `<p>` will be on top or below this element. Easily wrap your "pipe"-symbol inside a `<span>` which is the inline brother of the `<div>` element (which is an block element).

To sum this up, take this code snippet:

```
<p>
  Some text before the <span id="blink">|</span>
</p>
```

> For better understanding / testing for yourself check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s81kuzwr/)

Comment: Thank you so much Gerrit Halfmann! This will work for me! I have not realized <span> existed until now!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline` css property.

```css
p {display: inline;}
```

```html
<p>hii</p><p id="blink">|</p>
<script>
 var blacktime = 400;
 var whitetime = 400;

 setTimeout(whiteFunc,blacktime);
 function whiteFunc(){
 document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "white";
 setTimeout(blackFunc,whitetime);
}
 function blackFunc(){
 document.getElementById("blink").style.color = "black";
 setTimeout(whiteFunc,blacktime);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Though not technically wrong, it's still incorrect. You've wrapped the blinker in a P. A p is for a Paragraph, which it is not. Just use a span, which is display:inline by itself, not needed any CSS

Comment: Also, this will mess everything up as the other paragraphs should be block (their default). If you have two paragraphs of text, you want them exactly as that, two paragraphs. Making them inline will act weird.

Comment: @Martijn you are right. But I try to solve the problem by using the same tag that J. Doely used.

Comment: Yes, we can also do it without any css like that **hii<span id="blink">|</span>**

Comment: Yeah, but you've made it worse. You fixed a tiny problem, by creating a big mess. You should always give a good ansewr, not a litteral answer :)